# Does making objects Parcelable cause inconsistencies with strong references?

Tags: android, bundle, parcel

I am trying to convert the model of my android application to use bundles (up to now it was stored in Application and all views requested data directly from it)

I was wondering if parcelling and unparcelling would cause problems if I have strong references to each object.

For example, let us say that I have this object

```
class Father {
    String name; 
    bool has_kids;
}
```

And this class

```
class Child {
    String name;
    Father father;
}
```

assuming I make both parcelable, and I have a structure similar to this:

a Father with name "f1" with three children whose father variable refers to that father

when this get parcelled into a bundle and the unparcelled on the other side will I have three children with references to one father object with the name "f1" or will each one have its own reference to a different father with the same name?

I tried to test it and it seems to work with the first logic, however I can't really simulate low memory conditions on my phone (in which case the bundles are stored and then retrieved again) so as to be absolutely certain this will work

Comment: I wouldn't even bother about this ... Parcellable is not meant to use like this ... Common way is: implement and use ContentProvider save Child in it ... pass only Uri to the element ... and on the other side load from CP from Uri whatever you want

Comment: Do you add the same `Father` object to the 3 child classes? You could run a simply test by checking the objects are **equal** rather than just of the same parameters?

Comment: @Selvin well I'm going by the android developers examples, and it seems when they wish to pass an argument to a fragment, they pass it through a bundle which is given to the instantiation of the fragment, from what I understood , this is because that way in case of low memory this helps restore your activity when it comes to the foreground after being disposed

Comment: @brandall yes I have created the objects with the same father, and the child2.father == child1.father operation returns true so they are indeed the same object, I am just wandering if this is happening because there is no need to parcel/unparcell the objects because there is no low memory problems, or because they bundling process indeed works like that